# Convert PowerPoint to Flash or Silverlight?

Tags: flash, microsoft-powerpoint, silverlight

I have a simple PowerPoint presentation and I would like to convert it to Flash or Silverlight. The presentation is a simple "Slide after Slide after Slide" and my first guess was to use OpenOffice Impress.

Sadly, the picture quality is awful. I would need the presentation to be in a specific format (900 Pixels wide and as high as it needs to be, usually 675 pixels)

Can you recommend any good, simple PowerPoint => Flash or Silverlight converter that does that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Free PowerPoint to Flash Converter](http://www.ispringsolutions.com/products/ispring_free.html):

> Spring Free works within PowerPoint,
>   transforming it into a fast and easy
>   Flash authoring tool. It is compatible
>   with any PowerPoint version
>   2000/XP/2003/2007 installed on a
>   Windows machine. To create Flash files
>   viewable on any device from your
>   PowerPoint presentations, just install
>   iSpring Free, open your PowerPoint
>   presentation, click Quick Publish and
>   get Flash slideshows from your PPT
>   presentations in just a few seconds.

[image: image1]

[image: image2]

Answer (score 2):

If you just want "pictures" of deck slides with no animation, there's a tool on http://codeplex.com called PPT to Silverlight. There is currently no other tool on the market that supports PPT to Silverlight (Electric Rain has some technology that they license though).

Otherwise, there are some really good tools for PPT to Flash. I used Articulate Presenter and Captivate from Adobe. Both are not cheap though. :(

Answer (score 1):

- [PPT2SWF](http://www.brothersoft.com/ppt2swf-personal-version2007-download-57649.html)

> PowerPoint to SWF Personal Version
>   2007 is an easy flash authoring
>   tool.It is a powerful PowerPoint
>   plug-in converts PowerPoint
>   presentation to Flash(SWF).Easy of
>   use, accurate conversion, and small
>   size. Fully functional version, for
>   personal, education and non-profit
>   org. only.  New feature:Luxury Output
>   Layout was added,which includes a
>   simplified and efficient thumbnail and
>   outline bar for quick and flexible
>   navigation purpose. Supports
>   PowerPoint 2007 now.

Answer (score 1):

A good free option can be found at the below listed address:

This tool is called authorPOINT lite.

[authorPOINT Lite](http://www.authorgen.com/authorpoint-lite-free/powerpoint-to-flash-converter.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

[Acoolsoft PPT to Flash](http://www.acoolsoft.com/powerpoint-to-flash-overview.html#105)

It works as an add-in of PowerPoint. Enables us to convert PowerPoint to flash movies.